# Enable OS X accessibility API with Java?

Tags: java, macos, accessibility-api

Its possible to Enable Accessibility API for a software developed with JavaFX?

Obs: I want to record keyboard input text.

Comment: I'm using [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) on MacOS to trigger global key strokes from anywhere. When I first run the App, MacOS prompts me with a request to enable under the "Accessibility" settings panel - is this the kind of thing you're talking about?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Yes, exactly this.